# Why Is this HTML producing two different results in Google Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, tailwind-css

I have a `<span>` text element that has a `relative` position and a child `<span>` that has an absolute position with a colored background, but it doesn't seem to be working properly on the Firefox browser. I am using Tailwind CSS ^2.2 and here is the HTML code snippet:

```
<h1 class="max-w-md mx-auto mt-1 text-blue-900 block text-[2rem] tracking-tight font-bold sm:text-5xl lg:text-4xl xl:text-5xl leading-snug sm:leading-snug lg:leading-snug xl:leading-snug">
  The premier
  <span class="relative px-0.5 whitespace-nowrap z-10">Spanish<span class="absolute inset-y-0 rounded-sm -left-1 -right-1 bg-blue-50" style="z-index:-1;"></span></span>
  immersion school of
  <span class="relative px-0.5 whitespace-nowrap z-10"> Los Angeles <span class="absolute inset-y-0 rounded-sm -left-1 -right-1 bg-red-100" style="z-index:-1;"></span></span>
</h1>
```

Here is a screenshot of result in Chrome:

[image]

And here is a screenshot of result in Firefox:

[image]

As you can see the background over "Los Angeles" isnt applied properly.

I also created a Tailwind Play component here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/zCdDLVtjAE.
You can open it in the different browsers to see the difference. What is causing this difference and what do you think I can change to make it consistent across the different browsers?

Comment: The HTML is super weird. Why is background done via blank `span` tags? Just for rounded corners? You can create rounded backgrounds via shaping of the `span` element that has the text so why are you doing this?

Comment: That's a good question. I laughed at the realization of how dumb the HTML is structured. I wrote this months ago, so I can't currently think of why I would structure it this way. I updated it to the simple way you mentioned. Styles look fine now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although, not sure of the exact cause but it's due to the extra leading space in the " Los Angeles". If you change it to "Los Angeles" then it works fine.

```html
<h1 class="max-w-md mx-auto mt-1 text-blue-900 block text-[2rem] tracking-tight font-bold sm:text-5xl lg:text-4xl xl:text-5xl leading-snug sm:leading-snug lg:leading-snug xl:leading-snug">
  The premier
  <span class="relative px-0.5 whitespace-nowrap z-10">Spanish<span class="absolute inset-y-0 rounded-sm -left-1 -right-1 bg-blue-50" style="z-index:-1;"></span></span>
  immersion school of
  <span class="relative px-0.5 whitespace-nowrap z-10">Los Angeles <span class="absolute inset-y-0 rounded-sm -left-1 -right-1 bg-red-100" style="z-index:-1;"></span></span>
</h1>
```

Demo :https://play.tailwindcss.com/zCdDLVtjAE